# Cannot call method 'trustAsResourceUrl' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, url, directive

I'm using angular to display an iframe of Youtube. In order to, I've used $sce to trust external URL but I've got an error that I can't solve... Maybe someone could explain it to me

Controller.js

```
.controller('DetailsCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$http',
    function($scope, $routeParams, $http, $sce) {
        $scope.loading = true;
      $scope.url = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl('//www.youtube.com/embed/4wOoLLDXbDY');
        $http.get('projects/' + $routeParams.projectId + '.json').success(function(data) {
          $scope.project = data;
          $scope.loading = false;
        });
    }]);
```

Details.html

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" ng-src"{{url}}" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Error in Console

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'trustAsResourceUrl' of undefined
    at new <anonymous> (http://localhost:9000/scripts/controllers/details.js:22:25)
    at invoke (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3869:17)
    at Object.instantiate (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3880:23)
    at http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:7134:28
    at link (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js:913:26)
    at nodeLinkFn (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:6579:13)
    at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:5986:15)
    at publicLinkFn (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:5891:30)
    at boundTranscludeFn (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:6005:21)
    at controllersBoundTransclude (http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:6600:18) <div ng-view="" class="ng-scope">
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this. You need to specify `$sce` as a [dependency](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di).

```
.controller('DetailsCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$http', '$sce',
    function($scope, $routeParams, $http, $sce) {
        $scope.loading = true;
      $scope.url = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl('//www.youtube.com/embed/4wOoLLDXbDY');
        $http.get('projects/' + $routeParams.projectId + '.json').success(function(data) {
          $scope.project = data;
          $scope.loading = false;
        });
    }]);
```

Comment: Oh yes, I've seen my error. Thank You! No more error, however my video doesn't display... In the inspector I can see `<iframe width="560" height="315" src"{{url}}"="" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>` so {{url}} is not replace by Angular. If I had <p>{{url}}</p> above the iframe, it display the url... So I don't understand why it doesn't work in the iframe.

Comment: @semlh Looks like you're just missing the = sign after src

Comment: Aw I'm feeling ashamed haha. Too much time on this problem, I've forgotten the basics... Thank you so much !

Answer (score 0):

You must enter `$Sec` in your controller:

```
.controller('DetailsCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$http', '$sce',
    function($scope, $routeParams, $http, $sce)

$sce
```